# Search specific word inside document using ssh

Tags: 14.04, ssh, find

Currently i have to analize some big files looking for a espefic word in **.css**  located on my **/var/www/** located on ubuntu server (ssh).
There a way to make something like Ctrl+f in windows programatically in ubuntu to search the words ?

Or just i have to use some ftp tool to download my file in windows and looking for there ?

Comment: You can use command line tools e.g. `grep` for this..please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/624102/edit) and add some content of the file and what you want to search out from that..

Comment: Try `grep -n '.css' file.txt` , if you want `.css` coming anywhere in a word..on the other hand if you want the words containing `.css` try `grep -Pn '(?<=^)|(?<=\s).css(?=$|\s)' file.txt` .....you will get the lines containg `.css` along with line numbers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are connected via `ssh` there are many commands you can use.

You could use `grep searchString /var/www/file.css/` to display all occurrences of `searchString`.

Or you could display the file with `less /var/www/file.css` then press <kbd>/</kbd> and type the word you are searching for. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to jump to the first occurrence of the word and <kbd>n</kbd> to cycle through the other ones step by step.